# Every combination of $v = (1, -2, 1)$ and $w = (0, 1, -1)$ has components that add to ________.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am solving some problems in Linear Algebra text book.
The question is filling in the blank of the following sentence.

> Every combination of $v = (1, -2, 1)$ and $w = (0, 1, -1)$ has components that add to ________.

The answer is *zero*. I hope you to explain why is *zero* the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A linear combination of $v$ and $w$ is $$av + bw = a(1, -2, 1) + b(0, 1, -1) = (a, -2a, a) + (0, b, -b) = (a, b - 2a, a - b).$$ The sum of the components is $$a + (b-2a) + (a - b) = 0.$$

Comment: This is a much better answer than mine, thanks

Comment: Ah. Thank you for answer. If the question were "What is the sum of the components of linear combination of v and w?", I could solve it....... actually I couldn't understand "that add to ____"... Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is zero because if you add up the components of $v$, to get $1-2+1=0$, and similarly for $w$, you get $0+1-1=0$. So for any combination of the two, the components will still add to zero