# How components of v and of w add to zero while help differentiating column and row

Tags: linear-algebra

Every combination of v = (1,-2,1) and w = (0,1 ,-1) has components that add to? Find c and d so that cv+ dw = (3,3,-6). Why is (3,3,6) impossible? (Source: Gilbert Strang Introduction to Linear Algebra).

In the solution manual, it is given:
The components of every cv + dw add to zero because the components of v and of w
add to zero. c = 3 and d = 9 give (3, 3,−6). There is no solution to cv+dw = (3, 3, 6)
because 3 + 3 + 6 is not zero.

So it is given the components of v and of w add to zero.

I find v + w = (1,-1,0). So not sure how v + w = 0 in this context.

Updated query: Will the solution remain the same or vary if v and w in 3x1 form instead of 1x3 form: v = $
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
-2 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$, w =
$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
-1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

Comment: The components of a vector are its entries.  The sum of the components of $v$ is $1 - 2 + 1 = 0$; the sum of the components of $w$ is $0 + 1 - 1 = 0$.  The sum of the components of $v + w$ is $1 - 1 + 0 = 0$.

Comment: So it is safe to say 1,-2, 1 of v are multiples of same unit in coordinate axes or scalar numbers. That is, unlike column matrices, it is not that 1 is of x axis, -2 of y axis, and 1 of z axis, where x,y,z can be kind of apples and oranges, something of different scale and so cannot be added like the way it is done when we do 1−2+1=0 .

Comment: The word "zero" in this context unfortunately has different meanings.  There is the *zero vector*, the vector who when added to other vectors doesn't change them (*in this context, the vector who has every entry equal to zero*).  Then, there is the *zero scalar* (*i.e. the "number zero"*), the element of the scalar field who when added to another scalar doesn't change them, the element of the scalar field who when multiplied to a vector makes the result the zero vector.  Here, as alluded to before, these vectors $v,w$ and any linear combination have their entries adding to the *zero scalar*.

Comment: As for if you do or don't want to add entries together... for row vectors or for column vectors or otherwise... that all depends on context.  There is no rule saying you can't, and in this problem we are pointing out the (*somewhat*) interesting property that the elements of $v$ add to the zero scalar, the elements of $w$ add to the zero scalar, and that the elements of any linear combination of these will always also add to the zero scalar... regardless of what linear combination of them it happened to be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Every combination of $v = (1, -2, 1)$ and $w = (0, 1, -1)$ has components that add to \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336665/every-combination-of-v-1-2-1-and-w-0-1-1-has-components-that-a)  Also [sum of the components of a vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4326862/sum-of-the-components-of-a-vector?rq=1)

Comment: @JMoravitz Revised this query and not sure if accessible to you as marked duplicate.

Comment: Still effectively the same. As to the question of row vectors vs column vectors, they are interchangeable in most situations and all of the explanation that worked for the one version obviously works for the other.